# Flutter built apk when opened in samsung phone is opening Samsung heath app

Tags: android, flutter, apk, samsung-mobile

I am building a grocery app in flutter. When I am running it in emulator it is running smoothly. But the moment I build the app using `flutter build apk` command and opening it in my **Samsung m34** phone, it is opening samsung health app.

I am transferring my apk file through whatsapp from my laptop to phone. If it helps in resolving the query.

Comment: You can connect to your phone with PC/Mac with adb.

Comment: Actually rahul I want to send the apk to my client